# iframe not working when trying to retrieve data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, iframe

I'm trying to make a WYSIWYG for my webpage.  I followed a tutorial I found, which works great except for when I try to add php code to retrieve data from mySQL so I can update my pages.  Is there something I need to add to the iframe so that it will work with the server?

The iframe text area stops working when I add the php code to retrieve the data from mySQL.

When I test this with a URL like this

http://localhost/site-test/admin-cms/pages/edits/test-page.php

The text box works, but when I try to use my URL that looks like this

http://localhost/site-test/admin-cms/pages/edits/edit-main-btn.php?main_page=9

The text box stops working.

Is there some code missing from my iframe that makes it work between all my pages so I can edit my pages?

```
<!--!!!!!This needs to Be HERE Don't MOVE IT!!!!!! -->
<?php require_once("includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<!--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->

<?php $layout_context = "admin-w/navigation"; ?>

<?php include_layout_template('header.php'); ?>


<form action="my_parse_file.php" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
<p>Menu name:
        <input type="text" name="btn_name" value="" />
      </p>
      <p>Position:
        <select name="position">
            <?php
            $main_new = new Main_Navigation;
                $main_btnNav_set = $main_new->find_all_main_cmsNav_btns(false);
                $main_btnNav_count = mysqli_num_rows($main_btnNav_set);
                for($count=1; $count <= ($main_btnNav_count + 1); $count++) {
                    echo "<option value=\"{$count}\">{$count}</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>Visible:
        <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> No
        &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" /> Yes
      </p>
<p>Entry Body:<br>
<div id="wysiwyg_cp" style="padding:8px; width:700px;">
 <input type="button" onClick="iBold()" value="B"> 
  <input type="button" onClick="iUnderline()" value="U">
<input type="button" onClick="iItalic()" value="I">
<input type="button" onClick="iFontSize()" value="Text Size">
<input type="button" onClick="iForeColor()" value="Text Color">
<input type="button" onClick="iHorizontalRule()" value="HR">
<input type="button" onClick="iUnorderedList()" value="UL">
<input type="button" onClick="iOrderedList()" value="OL">
<input type="button" onClick="iLink()" value="Link">
<input type="button" onClick="iUnLink()" value="UnLink">
</div>
<!-- Hide(but keep)your normal textarea and place in the iFrame replacement     for it -->
<textarea style="display:none;" name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px  solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>
<!-- End replacing your normal textarea -->
</p>
<br /><br /><input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit Data"   onClick="javascript:submit_form();"/>
</form>

<?php include_layout_template('test-footer.php'); ?>
```

In the header.php file I have

```
<body onLoad="iFrameOn();">
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? what errors are you getting?

Comment: You could also remove all the irrelevant code from your question (thinking mostly of all the JS functions).

Comment: The iframe text area stops working when I add the php code to retrieve the data from mySQL.

Comment: What does `var_dump($main_btnNav_set);` give you?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)[9]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null